# Optimatility conditions - Sufficient condition in conjunction with necessary condition

Tags: logic, optimization, notation

Is the sufficient condition for a maximum $f''(x)<0$ only a *true* sufficient condition in conjunction with the necessary condition $f'(x)=0$?

Because a sufficient condition in the general sense is a simple 'if-then' statement, the second order condition is obviously not enough to find any form of extremum.

These two conditions are of course always checked sequentially, however the wording in my experience has always been that $f''(x)<0$ is *the sufficient condition* without amendments.

Comment: So, you already know that $f''(x)<0$ is not a sufficient condition (in the absence of $f'(x)=0$). So, what are you asking?

Comment: Hi Gerry, I'm simply wondering whether my hypothesis/interpretation is correct, in spite of what I've been taught for more than half a decade.

Comment: I don't know what you have been taught, and I don't know what the wording has been in your experience, and you haven't cited any examples of either. I do know, and so do you, that there is no local maximum if $f'(x)\ne0$, regardless of the sign of $f''(x)$, and that there is a local maximum if $f'(x)=0$ and $f''(x)<0$. What more do you want?

Comment: Oh I simply the confirmation that the sufficient condition is in fact $f'(x)=0 \land f''(x)<0$ instead of just $f''(x)<0$ or alternatively the pointer that my conceptual understanding of 'sufficient condition' is insufficient.

Comment: Well, haven't I confirmed that? [and why do you need any outside confirmation, when you know perfectly well that it is so?]

Comment: Thank you, Gerry!